# Nginx 504 Gateway Time Out with Unicorn and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, digital-ocean

I'm running a Rails 4 app on a Digital Ocean VPS and I'm getting an Nginx 504 gateway time out error on a particular HTTP request. All requests succeed, but this particular one does not. I am running in production mode and there are **no errors or exceptions in my Rails log**.

The Nginx log looks like this:

```
2014/04/23 05:08:22 [error] 6946#0: *109805 upstream timed out 
(110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client:
174.126.176.107, server: new.pilotpro.com, request: 
"GET /dropbox/sync?right_now=1398115006.949 HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"http://127.0.0.1:8080/dropbox/sync?right_now=1398115006.949", 
host: "new.pilotpro.com"
```

And the Unicorn log looks like this:

```
E, [2014-04-23T04:52:06.285058 #5424] ERROR -- : worker=1 PID:5429 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
E, [2014-04-23T04:52:06.297947 #5424] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5429 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=1
I, [2014-04-23T04:52:06.298207 #5424]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2014-04-23T04:52:06.299481 #5457]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=5457
```

As far as I can tell nothing is wrong other than the fact that the request is timing out. Is this simply a matter of increasing Nginx's timeout limits?

I'd appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: It's about unicorn master process killing it's worker process when it's taking too long to process a request(default is 60s). So it's not about increasing Nginx's connection timeout, but increasing unicorn's timeout value or optimizing your application code so that it finishes within 60s.

Comment: Thanks, Dean. I've been researching this since your post, and I can't seem to determine what the process it that's taking so long. I've tried using `top` to watch the processes, but the offending process comes and goes so fast I can't get its name. 

Any suggestions on narrowing down the cause?

Comment: The worker process are basically the same, all forked by master. It's not about which process, but which particular request takes too much time to process. Look at you nginx error log, that particular request is your problem. You won't see anything in you rails log coz unicorn master process simply kills (-9 looks like) that worker process, so it won't even have the chance to write any log. So all you can do is to match the time stamp in nginx error log & unicorn stderr(timeout, killing), if those happens in the same time, then you know what request is too slow